# HTML: Display key in an input field

Tags: html

is it possible to view the key in an input field but when submitted the value must be in `abcde`? Its like `<option value="abcde">Apple</option>` but I don't want to use `option` in this case. The key-value is `{'Apple': 'abcde'}`.

When submitted:

```
<input id=section name=section value=abcde>
```

When viewed (inside the input box):

```
Apple
```

Comment: What mechanism should be used to assign a key to free input? Does it need to use static HTML or JavaScript is an option?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Can we get the result through static HTML?

Comment: I have thousands of key-value pairs and I don't want to iterate them via select-option since it will consume memory from my database every time the page is loaded. So I decided to only use this approach, as possible I don't want to use A-JAX / JSON at this moment.

Comment: In HTML5 the [`<input>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) accepts a [`list` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-list) to link the control with a [<datalist> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) to suggest from, but there's no provision to display a value and submit a different one. Plus if you want to JavaScript-free then these HTML5 fancies aren't a good fit either.

Comment: Couldn't you just use custom attributes ?

Answer (score 1):

In plain *static* HTML5, the *closest* fit is probably using a [`list` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-list) in the [`<input>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) to link the control to a [`<datalist>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist). That way you basically get auto-complete for free:

```html
<label>First choice:  <input name="fruit1" value="" list="fruits"></label>
<label>Second choice: <input name="fruit2" value="" list="fruits"></label>

<datalist id="fruits">
  <option value="abcde">Apple</option>
  <option value="fghij">Orange</option>
  <option value="klmno">Strawberry</option>
</datalist>
```

However, there's no mechanism to display a value and submit a different one. The above snippet will face users with your internal keys.

*(Needless to say, this could be easily solved with JavaScript.)*